# How to add data gateway to SQL connector with ARM template

Tags: sql, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to connect to a database through a data gateway (SQL Server Connector) with ARM templates. But I'm not sure if I miss something because I'm getting connection error with the gateway.

This is what I have so far in my api connection:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_sql_name": {
            "defaultValue": "sql",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_sql_displayName": {
            "defaultValue": "displaynameDB",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "server": {
            "defaultValue": "SERV01",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "database": {
            "defaultValue": "DB01",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "authType": {
            "defaultValue": "windows",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "username": {
            "defaultValue": "USER01",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "password": {
            "defaultValue": "PASS123",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_sql_name')]",
            "location": "northeurope",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('connections_sql_displayName')]",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "parameterValues": {
                    "server": "[parameters('server')]",
                    "database": "[parameters('database')]",
                    "authType": "[parameters('authType')]",
                    "username": "[parameters('username')]",
                    "password": "[parameters('password')]"
                },
                "api": {

                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/{sub-id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northeurope/managedApis/', parameters('connections_sql_name'))]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is a part of my logic app under inputs:

```
"gateway": {
                                "gatewaySettings": {
                                    "connectionDetails": [
                                        "[parameters('gatewayServer')]",
                                        "[parameters('gatewayDatabase')]"
                                    ],
                                    "credentialType": "Windows",
                                    "dataSourceType": "sql"
                                },
                                "type": "gatewaySetting"
                            },
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: what's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the gateway block from the Logic App definition and changing the connection definition to this:

```json
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
    "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
    "name": "[parameters('connections_sql_name')]",
    "location": "northeurope",
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('connections_sql_displayName')]",
        "customParameterValues": {
            
        },
        "parameterValues": {
            "server": "[parameters('server')]",
            "database": "[parameters('database')]",
            "authType": "[parameters('authType')]",
            "username": "[parameters('username')]",
            "password": "[parameters('password')]",
            "gateway": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/{sub-id}/resourceGroups/{gateway-resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways/{gateway-name}"
            }
        },
        "api": {
            "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/{sub-id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northeurope/managedApis/', parameters('connections_sql_name'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation isn't very helpful regarding the **gateway** property in connection resources.